# Returning instances allocated in the heap vs in the stack

Tags: c++, heap-memory, allocation, stack-memory

It's been many, many years since the last time I did something in C++. These days, someone asked me for some help on a school project in C++, and I was intrigued by a "feature" of the language I've seen, which worked fine but I expected it not to work.

As I remember, I can have instances of classes created either on the heap or on the stack:

```
int main() {
  MyClass *inHeap = new MyClass();
  MyClass inStack = MyClass();
}
```

As far as I can tell, the first *variable*, `inHeap`, will make the compiler reserve some stack in the `main` stack frame enough to hold a pointer (4 bytes? 8 bytes? something like that), which points to the actual instance of the object which lives in the heap.

Also, the second *variable*, `inStack`, will make the compiler reserve stack enough to hold the complete instance of `MyClass` right there in the `main` stack frame.

Now, on to my question. Suppose I have a function that is supposed to return an instance of `MyClass`. At first, I thought it could only return instances in the heap:

```
MyClass *createInHeap() {
  return new MyClass();
}
int main() {
  MyClass* inHeap = createInHeap();
}
```

But what I've seen is the following:

```
MyClass createInStack() {
  MyClass c = MyClass();
  return c;
}
int main() {
  MyClass inStack = createInStack();
}
```

What exactly is going on here?

- Is the memory for the instance of `MyClass` reserved in the stack frame of `createInStack`? If this is the case, will this code force the instance to be *copied* to the stack frame of `main` when the function `createInStack` returns? How is this copy performed, ie, is it just automatically calling the copy constructor for me in the `main` function?
- Another possibility I thought about was that the compiler would be smart enough to already reserve the memory for the `MyClass` instance in the `main` stack frame. Does this exist? Is this some kind of *optimization* to avoid making a possibly expensive copy?

As a final question, when I have an instance created in the stack, when exactly is its destructor called? When the scope in which it was created finishes?

Comment: Unless I missed something, the answer is "yes" to everything you wrote :)

Comment: Notice, that `MyClass c();` does *not* create an instance of class `MyClass`, but rather declares a function that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `MyClass`. Same for `MyClass inStack();`.

Comment: `MyClass inStack();` is a function declaration; you mean `MyClass inStack;`. Apart from that, the answer is pretty much "yes".

Comment: Thanks, guys. I fixed that function call vs instance creation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are doing something like this:

```
MyClass createInStack() 
{
  MyClass return_value;
  return return_value;
}

int main() 
{
  MyClass inStack = createInStack();
}
```

Then yes, `c` is logically created on the stack in `createInStack()` and then a copy of it is logically returned and then copied into `inStack` in `main`.

There is a common misconception that returning by value is inefficient because of all this logical copying.  However, due to named return value optimization, this isn't what actually happens in practice.  The construction step in the calling function is just deferred to the called function.  It would be something like this (pseudocode):

```
void createInStack(MyClass &return_value)
{
  return_value.MyClass(); // construct return_value (not actually valid syntax)
}

int main()
{
  MyClass inStack; // except don't call the constructor
  createInStack(inStack);
}
```

So as you can see, no actual copying happens.

In addition, the compiler may do other optimizations.  It may even decide that `inStack` is never used and just not create it, but you can be pretty sure that at least the named return value optimization will avoid a lot of copying.

Answer (score 1):

It should also be pointed out that calling `new` is not a cost-less operation. It can have significant overhead, and it certainly uses more memory than making a local copy on the stack - and of course, the `delete` has to be handled and remembered by the programmer, and will also take more than zero time.

So it's, as usual, a design decision which is better, and understanding what is going on (as well as understanding the  "Return Value Optimization" already covered in a previous answer). A very large class will take a long time to copy, but a small class with just a few values in it, may well be faster to copy on the stack than allocating and freeing it.